# How to default an employeeid field to the current logged in user

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom inquiry screen which uses an employeeid as the header filter field.  What I'd like to do is default that employeeid field to the current logged in user, if possible.  I've tried the following, but both give me a cast error (version 5.3.2562):

```
1.)  [PXDBDefault(typeof(Search<EPEmployee.bAccountID, 
                         Where<EPEmployee.bAccountID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>>>))]

2.)  [PXDBDefault(typeof(AccessInfo.userID))]
```

Here's the entire DAC code for the filter field:

```
    #region EmployeeID
    public abstract class employeeID : IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXInt]
    [PXDBDefault(typeof(AccessInfo.userID))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Employee ID")]
    [PXSelector(typeof(Search<EPEmployee.bAccountID,
                       Where<EPEmployee.status, Equal<SetupTypes.active>>>),
                typeof(EPEmployee.acctCD),
                typeof(EPEmployee.acctName),
                SubstituteKey = typeof(EPEmployee.acctCD),
                DescriptionField = typeof(EPEmployee.acctName))]
    public virtual int? EmployeeID { get; set; }
#endregion
```

What's the correct way to obtain this?

Update 6/30/2017:
After implementing the solution (using PXDefault instead of PXDBDefault) as follows:

```
 [PXDefault(typeof(Search<EPEmployee.bAccountID,
                   Where<EPEmployee.bAccountID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>>>))]
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the SQL Table where EmployeeID is defined and the type of the EmployeeID in that Table

Answer (score 1):

We have a non filter field in a transaction able that defaults to the current employee.

This should work:

```
[PXDefault(typeof(Search<EPEmployee.bAccountID, 
                     Where<EPEmployee.bAccountID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>>>))]
```

Note that you do not want to use `PXDBDefault` for default values unless they are values coming from a parent DAC when linked with `PXParent`. Use `PXDefault` for defaults.

If this does not work in your filter, try `PXUnboundDefault` in place of `PXDefault`.

Edit 6/30/2017: new error might be on your selector. There is an employee selector already available. Remove your `PXSelector` and use `[PXEPEmployeeSelector]` on your field and see if this solves your error between uniqueidentifier and int

Comment: updated. Try using [PXEPEmployeeSelectorAttribute] in place of PXSelect

Answer (score 1):

AccessInfo.userID seems to be a GUID. In order to avoid the casting error you need to relate AccessInfo.userID to EPEmployee.userID while searching for EPEmployee.bAccountID. Final code should look like this:

```
    #region EmployeeID
    public abstract class usrEmployeeID : IBqlField
    {
    }
    [PXEPEmployeeSelector]
    [PXUnboundDefault(typeof(Search<EPEmployee.bAccountID,
                 Where<EPEmployee.userID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>>>))]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Employee ID")]
    public virtual int? UsrEmployeeID { get; set; }
    #endregion
```